# Failed to save using SelectMultiple in Django

Tags: django

I've got a problem to save in DB data using "Select Multiple Field"
My code looks like:

**Models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    statement_title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author,blank=True)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['__all__']
        
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.Textarea(attrs={'type': 'text',
                                           'placeholder': 'Book title'}
            'author': forms.SelectMultiple()
        }
```

If I add a new object everything is saving but without the author, but if I save author in admin page I can display authors in book-detail view.

Of course, I tried many solutions to solve this problem but nothing solved my problem.
I know I'm made a mistake but I don't have an idea where... Maybe I should add something extra in views.py?
I'll be very grateful for any tips and clues.

**EDIT:**

I'm enclosing views.py (*edit_book* is similar like *add_book*). It's just a typical view function. When I trying to display author id it's working correctly.

**views.py**

```
def edit_book(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BookForm(request.POST, instance=book)
        if form.is_valid():
            book = form.save(commit=False)
            print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
            print(book.author.all)
            for author in form.cleaned_data['author']:
                print(author.id)
            book.save()
            return redirect('book_details', book.id)
    else:
        form = BookForm(instance=book)
    return render(request,
                  'books/book/book_new.html',
                  {'form': form})
```

Comment: Can you share your *view*?

Comment: Sure, I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't save the form with `form.save(commit=False)`. A `ModelForm` can only save `ManyToManyField`s with `commit=True` (or later with `.save_m2m()`) as is discussed in the [Django documentation on *the `save()` method*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> Another side effect of **using `commit=False`** is seen when your **model has a many-to-many relation with another model**. If your model has a many-to-many relation and you specify `commit=False` when you save a form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the many-to-many relation. This is because it isn’t possible to save many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the database.

But here the simplest approach is simply to let the form itself save the object:

```
def edit_book(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST, instance=book)
        if form.is_valid():
            book = form.save()  # ← will save many-to-many fields
            return redirect('book_details', book.id)
    else:
        form = BookForm(instance=book)
    return render(
        request,
        'books/book/book_new.html',
        {'form': form}
    )
```

The reason Django can not save a many-to-many relation itself is because *first* the object you create needs to be created at the database side, to have a primary key. Only then the [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) can be populated with elements.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helps solve this problem, now I see my mistake, I reuse old code, and I only focused on the *forms.py* file; I assumed the problem might be in the view file but I didn't notice the save() method.